# Как отправлять ссылки и упоминания через telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

В файле message.txt у меня хранится текст, к примеру:

```
Строка 1
Строка 2
@usr
https://t.me/usr
```

Передача значения в переменную:

```
msgtosend = open("_txt/message.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
```

Отправка сообщения:

```
client.send_message(chat_num, msgtosend, parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Проблема в том, что сообщение в телеграме не подсвечивает @ и ссылку.
Иногда не подсвечивает и @ usr полностью
При должном образе, выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом с телефона, все нормально отображается, но с desktop версии, ни один из пользователей не может перейти на ресурс. При нажатии на @ usr пишет ошибку "имя @sr не найдено"(съедая первую букву)

Может кто знает, подскажет в чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Ваша проблема у меня не воспроизводится и всё штатно отрабатывает как на десктопной версии, так и на телефоне.